# Unable to remove spaces between strings from a file

Tags: bash, jenkins, amazon-s3

I have a file whose contents are like below.

$ cat test

```
static2 deploy

TDPlanValidator-Prod
```

I am trying upload contents from these directories to s3 bucket. The issue is s3 doesnt accept spaces and hence I am getting an error. For this to be done, I am trying to remove space between  "static2 deploy". This file will have around 400 entries and some of them will have directories with space in it like "static2 deploy". The script which I have written is not able to do that. The script and the output is below.

```
for i in `cat test`;do var="$( echo "$i" | tr -d ' ' )"; echo $var;done
```

static2

deploy

TDPlanValidator-Prod

I have tried sed too but that also doesnt work. I want output as below so that I can push it in s3 bucket

static2deploy

Can someone please help me out here? I have been trying things since yesterday but have been unable to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by below `sed` command

```
echo "static2 deploy" | sed "/static2/s/ //g"
```

How will it work? sed first search for string `static2` and once found it will search for all the spaces in that line and removes them.

So above command will output

```
static2deploy
```

But if you try with below:-

```
echo "static deploy" | sed "/static2/s/ //g"
```

Output would be

```
static deploy
```

So in your case you need to try with below:-

```
cat test | sed "/static2/s/ //g" > output.txt
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

`` for i in `cat test` `` loops over every string in the file and not every line.

This works:

```
cat test | while read line; do var="$( echo "$line" | tr -d ' ' )"; echo $var; done
```

or shorter if you only want to print the line:

```
cat test | while read line; do echo "$line" | tr -d ' '; done
```

Output:

```
static2deploy

TDPlanValidator-Prod
```